# What's wrong with my regexp?

Tags: php, regex

Why this code display `my/url/` instead of `my/url` ?

```
<?php

    $url = "/my/url/";
    echo preg_replace("#^/?(.+)/?$#","$1",$url);

?>
```

Comment: It might not solve your problem, but you need to escape your `/` characters like this: `\/`.

Comment: `trim($url, '/'); // does the job`

Comment: @JamWafles: That's not true when using `#` as the regex delimiter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `(.+)` is greedy by default. Make it ungreedy by adding `?` after the `+`.

```
echo preg_replace("#^/?(.+?)/?$#","$1",$url);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/8CLx9A8M).

You could also use `trim($url, '/')`, which is a better fit than a regex.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/function.trim.php)

```
$url = '/my/url/';
echo trim($url, '/');
```

Answer (score -1):

Because you have `.+` which will take any character. Make it any character EXCEPT a slash and it will work ;-).

Comment: No it won't - there's a slash in the middle of the string that needs to be matched.